# GeoIP database SQL query returns multiple results

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, geolocation, maxmind

I have installed the [Maxmind GeoIP database](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/) and now I am testing the results. I live in Amsterdam, so I did a IP query check with my own IP address, but I got 2 results back. Am I doing something wrong or is the data not clear?

**Database example:**

[image]

**SQL query:**

```
SELECT * FROM wp_geoip WHERE '{my-ip-address}' BETWEEN begin_ip_num AND end_ip_num;
```

**Results:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just store IP addresses as a varchar.  Well... you *can*, but it's wrong on something of a fundamental level.

The correct solution is to store the IP addresses as what they actually represent: unsigned 32 bit integers (`INT UNSIGNED`).

Convert the data, when you import it, using the [`INET_ATON()` built-in function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton), which converts a dotted-quad IPv4 address into an unsigned integer.

Query the data using the inverse function:

```
WHERE INET_NTOA('you.r.ip.add') BETWEEN begin_ip_num AND end_ip_num;
```

You will get better performanace if you index the begin and end columns in both directions, e.g.:

```
PRIMARY KEY(begin_ip_num,end_ip_num),
KEY(end_ip_num,begin_ip_num)
```

However... B-Trees are not optimal for this kind of search.

You will also be able to query it even faster, still, if you use a [spatial index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-extensions.html), as [Jeremy Cole explains in a blog post on the topic](http://blog.jcole.us/2007/11/24/on-efficiently-geo-referencing-ips-with-maxmind-geoip-and-mysql-gis/).  Note that he also goes into detail about the use of `INET_ATON()` and `INET_NTOA()`.

The spatial index concept blows some people's minds, since they assume "spatial" means only "*geo*spatial" but IP address *space* is, after all, still "space" and [R-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) indexes provided by MySQL's spatial extensions are much more optimal than B-Trees for searching for the boundaries of a "space" that a thing (like an IP address) occupies.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I have a low lvl knowledge of MySQL. So before I created the table in phpmyadmin and uploaded a CSV file with the import tool. But when you need to use built-in functionality you should make an import script right? Where should I start?

Comment: You can actually start with the table you already have.  Make a new table with the desired structure and columns in the same position, and then use `INSERT ... SELECT` to copy from table to table with the transformation: `INSERT INTO table2 SELECT INET_ATON(begin_ip_num), INET_ATON(end_ip_num), longitude, ... FROM table1;`.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 0):

It probably uses the `begin_ip_num` and `end_ip_num` as a `varchar`-field.

So an IP that starts with 92.11[...] will also be between the range in the first record. For the first records it checks for any string between `92.0` and `92.3`

So doing a text search will get you wrong results in this case. You could try to convert all IPs to a good searchable string. That means an ip like 92.31.255.255 should be converted to 092.031.255.255

If you do that for all you IPs you can do a proper search on them.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.formatIP ( @ip varchar(20) )
RETURNS varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  RIGHT('000' + PARSENAME(@ip,4), 3) + '.' + 
            RIGHT('000' + PARSENAME(@ip,3), 3) + '.' + 
            RIGHT('000' + PARSENAME(@ip,2), 3) + '.' + 
            RIGHT('000' + PARSENAME(@ip,1), 3)
END
```

Wrap that up in a function and use it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_geoip 
WHERE dbo.formatIP('{my-ip-address}') 
     BETWEEN dbo.formatIP(begin_ip_num) AND dbo.formatIP(end_ip_num);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it! Is also possible to change the type from varchar to unsigned int?

Comment: I got this syntax error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@ip varchar(20) )
RETURNS varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  RIGHT('000' + PAR' at line 1

Comment: I didn't see it was about a MySQL server. You've got a SQL-server tag in your post. I'm not sure how to rewrite it for MySQL

Comment: My apologies, my fault.